# What is this options object argument in the PassportJS local strategy for?

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

So, I'm authenticating users in my Node application with relational and passportJS. I couldn't find info on what the first argument in the passport local strategy does. Is this object providing a schema for the user to be stored in MySQL, where did `usernameField` and `passwordField` come from?

```
    passport.use('local-signup', new localStrategy({
        //provide a schema?
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        //pass back the entire request to the callback
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    //passport.authenticate() passes in the parsed out password and username
    function (req, username, password, done) {
    //....
    }
```

Comment: No, it's providing the information about what the input fields in your Form on client-side will have the value of their `name` attributes. If it's `<input name='name'>` you'll pass `{usernameField: 'name'}`

Comment: I understand that, but why use json to do that? Why not just run the `INSERT` query?

Comment: I run the query in the hidden body of the callback anyway, but why specify `usernameField`? Why not just query MySQL for the credentials?

Comment: MySQL doesn't even come into picture here. The purpose here is to tell passport which field is going to contain the username/password. Suppose you have a really unconventional `<input name='thisismyusername'>` field in your HTML Form, so then how will passport know that it's this "thisismyusername" field that has the username? That's its purpose.

Comment: passport passes the parsed username and password as arguments to the strategy callback. Why do I have to specify the key-value pairs in the preceeding object? It really escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

In you `server/auth/index.js`, you will find the different mappings for the different strategies you want to use.

Then, you will be able to check the strategy:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('../config/environment');
var User = require('../api/user/user.model');

// Passport Configuration
require('./login/passport').setup(User, config);

var router = express.Router();
router.use('/local', require('./local/index'));
```

Then, in `./local/index.js`

```
var passport = require('passport');
var auth = require('../auth.service.js');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log.req;

  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, "THAT´S BAD");
    if (!user) return res.json(404, {message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});
    var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.role);
    res.json({token: token, user:user});
  })(req, res, next)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, in ./local/passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Local = require('passport-local').Strategy;

exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  passport.use("local", new Local({
      usernameField: 'apikey',
      passwordField: 'apisecret'
    },

    function(apikey, apisecret, done) {
//THIS FUNCTION IS THE ONE YOU HAVE TO CHANGE TO YOUR MYSQL CODE TO CHECK WHETHER THE USER IS REGISTERED
      User.findOne({
        apikey: apikey,
        apisecret: apisecret
      }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          return done("YOUR API KEY HAS NOT AUTHORIZATION", false, { message: 'This email is not registered.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done("USER", user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });


};
```

**EDIT** As you see, I work with express, and I require the User model. it´s a mean fullstack app which runs with mongodb and mongoose. Anyway I think you´ll be able to use mysql (I strongly reccomend you to read about those fullstack generators) https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack
If you are kickstarting your app, consider to change mysql to mongodb--expressjs-angularjs-nodejs

Hope it helps !!